# Is there a way to make tkinter windows work independantly Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have been looking to create a code that opens a second tkinter window to display stuffs live while a program is running on my main window. However, doing so, my main window gets frozen during 5s and then displays stuff on my second window when it is completed.

Is there a way to live display in the second window ?

My code below:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import time

```
class PopUpLog(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.y=5
        
        tk.Button(self.master, text="Write in pop-up", command=self.write).pack(side="left")
        
        # canvas
        frameL = tk.Frame(self)
        frameL.pack(side="left", fill="both")
        
        self.canvasL = tk.Canvas(frameL, height=800, width=800)
        self.canvasL.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # scrollbar
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="v", command=self.canvasL.yview)
        vsb.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.canvasL.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self.canvasL.bind("<Configure>", lambda e:self.canvasL.configure(scrollregion=self.canvasL.bbox("all")))
        
    def write(self, text="hi im a pop-up"):
        for i in range(5):
            self.canvasL.create_text(5, self.y, anchor='nw', justify='left', text=text)
            self.y += 25
            time.sleep(1)
        
class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(self, text="Open window", command=self.popup).pack(side="left")        
        
    def popup(self):
        self.top = PopUpLog(self)
        self.top.geometry("400x400")
        self.top.title("pop-up")
        self.top.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

So far, the program runs for 5s and then displays everything in self.top. BUT I need a live display (made every time create_text is called) in self.top but I can't even get that.

I am sorry if this is redundant to another question asked but I couldn't find helpful enough information.
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep` is the reason why your window is freezing. This is the case for virtually any GUI toolkit.  If you want the updates to happen incrementally you can use the `after` method which will execute the callback you assign after a certain number of milliseconds.

Also there should only be one `mainloop`.  There is no need to start one per window and doing so could cause problems.

Here is an example using the `after` method:

```
class PopUpLog(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.y=5
        self.c=5  # counter

        tk.Button(self.master, text="Write in pop-up", command=self.write).pack(side="left")

        # canvas
        frameL = tk.Frame(self)
        frameL.pack(side="left", fill="both")

        self.canvasL = tk.Canvas(frameL, height=800, width=800)
        self.canvasL.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

        # scrollbar
        vsb = ttk.Scrollbar(self, orient="v", command=self.canvasL.yview)
        vsb.pack(side="left", fill="y")

        self.canvasL.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)
        self.canvasL.bind("<Configure>", lambda e:self.canvasL.configure(scrollregion=self.canvasL.bbox("all")))

    def write(self, text="hi im a pop-up"):
        if self.c > 0:
            self.canvasL.create_text(5, self.y, anchor='nw', justify='left', text=text)
            self.y += 25
            self.c -= 1  # reduce counter
            self.after(1000, self.write)  # call again in 1 second
        else:
            self.c = 5   # when counter is 0 reset counter


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Button(self, text="Open window", command=self.popup).pack(side="left")

    def popup(self):
        self.top = PopUpLog(self)
        self.top.geometry("400x400")
        self.top.title("pop-up")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = App()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This is more than helpful, I have not considered using self.after like this and it is a wonderful way to make things work !

Comment: Sure...  The moral of the story is, never ever use time.sleep in a gui application.  Glad I could help.

Comment: exactly ! self.after is so much more useful

Comment: @Valentin did you need any other help on this question?